# Is WM_CHAR message possible with a DialogBox() modal dialog?

Tags: winapi

I've been searching for the answer for hours, and a common solution is to respond to a `WM_GETDLGCODE` message, but I never get that message to respond to.

My example code is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

static LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg,
                                WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam) {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;
    case WM_GETDLGCODE:
        MessageBox(hDlg, "Got WM_GETDLGCODE", "DlgProc", MB_OK);
        return DLGC_WANTCHARS;
    case WM_CHAR:
        MessageBox(hDlg, "Got WM_CHAR", "DlgProc", MB_OK);
        break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   PSTR szcmdline, int iCmdShow) 
{
    DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
        NULL, DlgProc);
    return 0;
}
```

The dialog is a single edit box (1st tab stop) with the `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons.  The problem is, I get neither the `WM_GETDLGCODE` nor the `WM_CHAR` message. Before I continue down this path, I just want to know if this should work or not. Hooks is my next choice, but if `WM_CHAR` is available, it seemed like a less complicated solution if I want to keep the dialog modal.

Comment: I guess any `WM_CHAR` is sent to the edit box child window/control rather than to the dialog itself.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): [WM_CHAR doesn't work when IsDialogMessage() is used in the main loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66805573/10871073)

Comment: It might be more reliable to attach a console and print to stdout, rather than using `MessageBox`.

Comment: WM_CHAR good to the window with focus, which is probably the edit control. Similarly, WM_GETDLGCODE goes to the window that received the message, which is also probably the edit control. Dialog boxes themselves rarely get focus.

Comment: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-edit-controls#edit-control-default-message-processing) documents how an edit control responds to WM_GETDLGCODE.  If you want something else then you have to [subclass it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview).